# I want to export the array as a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I want to separate the array (1) and array (2) with commas or tabs
but
It is classified by each letter.

Now

T,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,p,r,o,b,a,b,l,y, ,t,h,e, ,h,i,g,h,e,s,t, ,8,/,1,0, ,I, ,c,o,u,l,d, ,g,i,v,e, ,f,o,r, ,a,n, ,8,/,1,0, ,m,o,v,i,e,.,T,h,e,r,e, ,a,r,e, ,s,o,m,e, ,v,e,r,y, ,g,o,o,d, ,m,o,m,e,n,t,s, ,i,n, ,E,n,d,g,a,m,e, ,a,n,d, ,t,h,a,t,',s, ,c,o,m,i,n,g, ,f,r,o,m, ,a, ,l,o,n,g, ,s,t,a,n,d,i,n,g, ,M,C,U, ,f,a,n, ,g,r,o,w,i,n,g, ,u,p, ,w,i,t,h, ,t,h,e,s,e, ,m,o,v,i,e,s,., ,I,n, ,c,r,e,a,t,i,n,g, ,a,n, ,e,x,t,e,n,s,i,v,e, ,a,n,d, ,e,m,o,t,i,o,n,a,l, ,j,o,u,r,n,e,y, ,f,o,r, ,a, ,l,o,t, ,o,f, ,t,h,e, ,M,C,U, ,c,h,a,r,a,c,t,e,r,s,",", ,i,t, ,a,b,s,o,l,u,t,e,l,y, ,s,u,c,c,e,e,d,s,.,E,n,d,g,a,m,e, ,u,l,t,i,m,a,t,e,l,y, ,i,s, ,a,n, ,e,x,c,e,l,l,e,n,t, ,c,o,n,c,l,u,s,i,o,n, ,t,o, ,o,v,e,r, ,1,0, ,y,e,a,r,s, ,o,f, ,f,i,l,m, ,b,u,t, ,I, ,f,e,e,l, ,t,h,e, ,p,l,o,t,',s, ,p,a,c,i,n,g, ,a,n,d, ,d,i,r,e,c,t,i,o,n, ,i,s, ,r,e,a,l,l,y, ,l,a,c,k,i,n,g, ,t,o, ,I,n,f,i,n,i,t,y, ,W,a,r,",", ,w,h,i,c,h, ,',t,r,i,m,m,e,d, ,t,h,e, ,f,a,t,', ,a,n,d, ,w,a,s, ,m,u,c,h, ,m,o,r,e, ,f,o,c,u,s,e,d, ,a,n,d, ,e,n,e,r,g,e,t,i,c,., ,G,r,a,n,t,e,d,

Want

[sentence A] , [sentence B] , [sentence C]

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('div','text show-more__control'):
    Result.append(link.text.strip())



with open("Filename", 'w', encoding='utf-8')as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for i in range(len(Result)):
        row = Result[i]
        writer.writerow(row)



#Result is separated into String type.
#Result [1] = "sentence A"
#Result [2] = "sentence B"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `"".join("T,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,e,x,a,m,p,l,e,., ,T,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,e,x,a,m,p,l,e,2,.".split(",")).split(". ")` Result: `['This is example', 'This is example2.']`

Comment: From which line you get the comma separated letters as output?

Comment: Also, are you sure "it is classified by each letter"? Strings in Python are iterable on their own, `"Example"[1]` will be "x". But you can work with it like a string, not character-by-character

Comment: @shaikmoeed After crawling
Put it in Result = [] array.

If only the result array is output separately, it will be output normally.
However, it is entered for every letter whether it is wrong to handle import CSV.

Comment: @h4z3 thank you!.  
I solved the problem without using CSV.

No problem now.
But I wonder
How do I know how import CSV works?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say, for example, running this code

```
for link in soup.find_all('div','text show-more__control'):
    Result.append(link.text.strip())
```

Gives us this list (`Result`):

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Now let's loop over the list

```
for i in range(len(Result)):
    row = Result[i]
```

`row` is equal to each element in the list as it's iterated over:

- in the first iteration it's 'foo'
- in the second iteration it's 'bar'
- in the third iteration it's 'baz'

each of these values is a *string*.

In the line

```
writer.writerow(row)
```

the `writerow` method expects an iterable, and assigns each item in the iterable to a separate column in the csv row.  So if it's passed 'foo' then the resulting row will be 'f,o,o'.

If there  is only one column - the element from `Result` in each row, the code needs to be like this:

```
with open("Filename", 'w', encoding='utf-8')as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for row in Result:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

We make `row` an element of a length 1 list to make `writerow` behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Thank you!
Your answer is perfect!

I can handle C #, JAVA well
Python seems too heterogeneous

Comment: Um ... I have one more question.
with '\ t'
I want to be able to identify it in the file.
writer.writerrow ([row])
writer.writerrow ("\ t")

Not like this.
Can not you use delimiter('\t')?

Comment: If you want to set tab as the delimiter do `writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')`.